# OpenMeetings latest release not unzipping

Tags: software-installation, tar, gzip

I am trying to install OpenMeetings for centos 6.5 32 bit but everytime I try to untar or unzip the latest binary release I get the following error:

```
tar -xzvf apache-openmeetings-3.0.0.tar.gz

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Then this with zip version

```
    unzip apache-openmeetings-3.0.0.zip
 Archive:  apache-openmeetings-3.0.0.zip
 End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
 a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
 latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
 the last disk(s) of this archive.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `apache-openmeetings-3.0.0.tar.gz` to see what kind of data the file actually contains. If this shows “gzip compressed data”, run `zcat foo.tar.gz | file -` to see what the compressed data is.

Occasionally, a bad combination of server/proxy/browser results in a file that is called `.gz` but has been decompressed. If this is the case, `file` will show something like “tar archive”, and you can decompress it with

```
tar -xvf apache-openmeetings-3.0.0.tar.gz
```

You can even use this command with a gzipped tar archive: GNU tar automatically detects several compression methods.

If the file is actually a text or HTML file, it contains an error or redirection page that was improperly detected. Read it to see what's going on.

If the file is empty, the download was aborted or incomplete. Wait for it to finish or restart it.

It's also possible that the file was damaged on the server.

Comment: Yes, it's happened a few times for me now but I always seem to get around it. Just was surprised to have this from official apache release page. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a proper answer but have it all working now,for some reason the links for latest release at apache didn't work for me with untar or unzip so instead went to http://fossies.org/linux/www/apache-openmeetings-3.0.0.tar.gz/webapps/openmeetings/docs/BuildInstructions.html  and that linked file did untar...I have no clue why downloaded tar file should untar and another not.

OpenMeetings is now up and running thanks to this excellent instruction http://blog.iandreev.com/?p=1255